# configuring ReplyingKafkaTemplate for multiple entities

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have 2 service (both spring boot on kotlin). Named it "client" and "server"
Due to some restriction I must use synchronous request-reply pattern with kafka. So I try to use ReplyingKafkaTemplate. My problem is that I need to use for multiple entities. Means creating multiple ReplyingKafkaTemplate, one for "FOO" second for "BAR". So in my code I create multiple KafkaConfig classes with setup each entity and one base config.

Also I exclude KafkaAutoConfig from loading. Below config for "server" side (w/o kreplying kafka template):

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
class KafkaConfig @Autowired constructor(
    @Value("\${kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private var bootstrapServers: String,
    @Value("\${kafka.consumer-group.name}")
    private var consumerGroup: String,
    @Value("\${kafka.consumer-group.id}")
    private var groupId: Number
) {

    @Bean("kafkaProducerConfig")
    fun producerConfigs(): MutableMap<String, Any> {
        return mutableMapOf(
            Pair(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "kafka1:9092,kafka2:9093,kafka3:9094"),
            Pair(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer::class.java),
            Pair(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer::class.java),
            Pair(ProducerConfig.ENABLE_IDEMPOTENCE_CONFIG, "true"),
            Pair(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "all"),
            Pair(ProducerConfig.MAX_IN_FLIGHT_REQUESTS_PER_CONNECTION, "5"),
            Pair(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, Int.MAX_VALUE.toString()),
            Pair(ProducerConfig.LINGER_MS_CONFIG, "20"),
            Pair(ProducerConfig.BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG, (32 * 1024).toString()),
            Pair(ProducerConfig.COMPRESSION_TYPE_CONFIG, "snappy")
        )
    }

    @Bean("kafkaConsumerConfig")
    fun consumerConfigs(): Map<String, Any> {
        return mutableMapOf(
            Pair(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "kafka1:9092,kafka2:9093,kafka3:9094"),
            Pair(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer::class.java),
            Pair(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer::class.java),
            Pair(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest"),
            Pair(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, consumerGroup + groupId)
        )
    }

    @Bean("kafkaAdminConfig")
    fun admin(): KafkaAdmin {
        val configs: MutableMap<String, Any> = HashMap()
        configs[ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG] = bootstrapServers
        return KafkaAdmin(configs)
    }
}
```

and one for FOO(BAR same config as foo instead of another entities and naming of bean) config is:

```
@Configuration
class KafkaConfigForFOO {

    @Value("\${kafka.topic.request-consumable-topic}")
    private lateinit var requestConsumableTopic: String

    @Value("\${kafka.request-reply.timeout-ms}")
    private lateinit var replyTimeout: Number

    @Bean("requestFOOTopicConfig")
    fun requestConsumableTopic(): NewTopic {
        val configs: MutableMap<String, String> = HashMap()
        configs["retention.ms"] = replyTimeout.toString()
        return NewTopic(requestConsumableTopic, 6, 3.toShort()).configs(configs)
    }

    @Bean("producerFactoryForFOO")
    @Autowired
    fun producerFactoryForFOO(@Qualifier("kafkaProducerConfig") producerConfigs: MutableMap<String, Any>):
        ProducerFactory<String, FOO> = DefaultKafkaProducerFactory(producerConfigs)

    @Bean("kafkaTemplateForFOO")
    @Autowired
    fun kafkaTemplateForFOO(@Qualifier("producerFactoryForFOO") producerFactory: ProducerFactory<String, FOO>):
        KafkaTemplate<String, FOO> = KafkaTemplate(producerFactory)

    @Bean("consumerFactoryForFOO")
    @Autowired
    fun consumerFactoryForFOO(@Qualifier("kafkaConsumerConfig") consumerConfigs: MutableMap<String, Any>):
        ConsumerFactory<String, FOO> = DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory(consumerConfigs, StringDeserializer(), JsonDeserializer(FOO::class.java))

    @Bean("kafkaListenerContainerFactoryForFOO")
    @Autowired
    fun kafkaListenerContainerFactoryForFOO(
        @Qualifier("consumerFactoryForFOO") consumerFactory: ConsumerFactory<String, FOO>,
        @Qualifier("kafkaTemplateForFOO") kafkaTemplate: KafkaTemplate<String, FOO>
    ):
        KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, FOO>> {
        val factory = ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, FOO>()
        factory.consumerFactory = consumerFactory
        factory.setReplyTemplate(kafkaTemplate)
        return factory
    }
}
```

And also too service class with kafka listener:

```
@Component
class FOOReplyingKafkaConsumer @Autowired constructor(
    private val fooService: FooService
) {
    @KafkaListener(topics = ["\${kafka.topic.request-FOO-topic}"], containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactoryForFoo", groupId = "\${spring.kafka.consumer.group-id}")
    @SendTo()
    fun cropListen(request: FOO): FOO{
        return FOO(fooService.getAllByIds(request.ids ?: mutableSetOf()).toMutableSet())
    }
}
```

Problem is if I remove bean naming from shared consumer/producer config spring creating circular dependencies between kafkaTEmpalte and producerFactory. When I return it back, spring do not see kafka props from  it and throw `Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: No resolvable bootstrap urls given in bootstrap.servers` due to cannot parse bootstrap-servers.

Also If I remove excluding KafkaAutoConfiguration, exception throw that ContainerListener cannot know witch configuration inject

With simple java spring kafka application with one template all is good.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need two consumer factories; type erasure means it's irrelevant at runtime.

Boot configures one as

```
ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(
```

Which is effectively `<Object, Object>` (or `<Any, Any>` in Kotlin).

The same factory can be used for both listeners.

Since you are using the JSON deserializer; the type is determined from the headers set on the sending side.

Same thing with the template.

```
public KafkaTemplate<?, ?> kafkaTemplate
```

It can be injected multiple times with different generic types or as `<Object, Object>`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for Gary Russell for right direction. I remove all configs except producer config, and kafkaTemplate. Autowire into kafkaTemplate default spring boot config with needed type.